# Mid Component Life Cycle API Call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

From my understanding fetching data is considered a side effect and should be within the use effect. But I'm wondering if this rule can be broken mid component lifecycle. It's obvious why useEffect is important for fetching data when the component initially mounts. It's less obvious after.

Here is an example of what I'm doing. It seems to work fine, and after the data is fetched the component rerenders.

```
function ComponentThatFetchesList() {
   const [list, setList] = useState([]);

   const fetchData = () => {
     asyncFetchData().then(data => {
        setList(list);
     });
   }

   return ( 
      <div>
         <button onClick={fetchData}>fetch data</button>
         <ui>{list.map(l => (<li>{l}</li>))}</ul>
      </div>
   );
}
```

But from my understanding fetching data is considered a side effect and should be within the use effect. So perhaps something like the following is recommended (I added searchText to have something to trigger the useEffect).

```
function ComponentThatFetchesList() {
   const [list, setList] = useState([]);
   const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

   useEffect(() => {
      asyncFetchData(searchText).then(data => {
         setList(list);
      });
   }, [searchText]);

   return ( 
      <div>
         <input box to enter search text>
         <button that sets search text>
         <ui>{list.map(l => (<li>{l}</li>))}</ul>
      </div>
   );
}
```

Am I at risk of introducing bugs to be found later if I go with the first method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome @daniel-longfellow to Stack Overflow

The method looks fine as the data loading occurs on a user event.
(*And to micro-optimization, you might wrap `fetchData` in `useCallback` but if there is no performance issue, it'd only it make it harder to read*).

You'd use the second (`useEffect`) when the component needs to fetch automatically or a state changes.

But as I do not know the exact use-cases, you can go with either one and refactor later on.

---

And lastly, this question might not be a good Stack Overflow topic as it's not a specific problem but can be opinionated ([a recommend question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)).

Please refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

I  as you are a new contributor so won't be aware of it .

Comment: Thanks! That clears things up for me. And I will keep the additional info in mind when asking questions in the future.